# How do I add value to the end of array

Tags: python, numpy

Very simple but had no clue about it.
How do I add 4 to the end of the param_array?

```
param_array = np.array([[1,2,3]])
print(param_array)
print(param_array.shape)
print()
param_array = np.append(param_array, 4)
print(param_array)
print(param_array.shape)

[[1 2 3]]
(1, 3)

[1 2 3 4]
(4,)
```

I need the array of

```
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

shape should be (1,4)

Comment: You have an array of arrays, you need to declare as np.array([1,2,3]) - with single square brackets

Comment: please explain clearly what u r trying to do

Comment: I need [[1,2,3,4]] later for the other function. not single square brackets

Comment: Reread the docs for `np.append`.  Note what it say about the `axis` parameter?  I generally discourage the use of `np.append`, because I see too many errors in its use.  To go from a (1,3) array to a (1,4) one, you need to concatenate on a (1,1) array on axis 1.  When joining arrays, shapes and dimensions are very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate a (1,1) array to a (1,3) to make a (1,4):

```
In [168]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3]])                                             
In [169]: arr1 = np.concatenate((arr, np.array([[4]])), axis=1)                 
In [170]: arr1                                                                  
Out[170]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Your use of `np.append` produced a (4,) because, according to the docs:

```
If `axis` is None, `out` is a flattened array.
```

If I specify the axis in `append`:

```
In [172]: np.append(arr, 4, axis=1)                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-172-ca20005ded46> in <module>
----> 1 np.append(arr, 4, axis=1)

<__array_function__ internals> in append(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in append(arr, values, axis)
   4698         values = ravel(values)
   4699         axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4700     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
   4701 
   4702 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

The error is in the `concatenate` line.  You need to specify the 2d addition, just as I did above:

```
In [173]: np.append(arr, [[4]], axis=1)                                         
Out[173]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

`np.append(A, B, axis)` is just another way of writing `np.concatenate((A,B), axis)`.  With both you have to pay attention to dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

To make the changes you seek you should mess a bit with the axis parameter. There is, however, a shortcut you could use: creating a new reshaped array after you append the new element.

```
param_array = np.append(param_array, 4).reshape((1,4))
```

It does exactly what you want (at least I think) and it's quite simpler.